Is it a good idea to perform I2C Communication in the ISR?
I am working with an I2C based sensor.  The requirement is that whenever some new data is ready, it generates an interrupt (hey, new data is ready, aka RDY.) What I have implemented currently is, I have connected that pin (RDY from sensor) to my MCU and I have configured it to generate an interrupt on the rising edge.
In the ISR of this pin's interrupt, I am performing at least two operations - reading the bytes (around 50) from the sensor and writing two bytes in a certain location in the sensor. This is necessary in order to tell the sensor: "Hey! I am done reading bytes from you, you may close the communication window now." If it helps, the I2C sensor has 16-bit addresses.
edit: It is a touchpad sensor. Hence realtime data of gestures like swipe, tap, etc. is needed.
Is it too much to do in the ISR? Should I just set a flag and do the reading and closing part in the main loop?

Depends on how you've architected the rest of the system. If your MCU has anything better to do with its time, then sitting inside the ISR and performing I2C comms is probably  a bad idea and you should only initiate the I2C comms there and then continue with more interrupt-based I2C to complete it while the MCU also does other stuff. But if your MCU has nothing else to do until the I2C is complete then there's not much harm in letting it sit in the ISR - although if that is the case then it's likely that you probably don't need to handle the sensor's interrupt with an ISR in your MCU anyway.

That's up to your requirements. You can spend a week in an interrupt if you want to. Generally, if you are able to perform what you want in the interrupt without problems and are unable to figure out another way of doing it then that's the way you have to do it. If the MCU is not doing anything else than waiting for interrupts, then it might just be waiting for the interrupt or poll the pin in a loop and it can do the transfer in main code, not interrupts.

At work we have CPU cores which are completely interrupt driven. We get an interrupt when a new command for the firmware arrives and do all the processing and execution in the interrupt subroutine. Thanks to nested interrupts we can even interrupt the interrupt if another message with a higher priority comes in. The main loop is a simple while(true) sleep();

Is it possible to do the read via DMA? If so, that would reduce the amount of time spent in an interrupt.

@stack-  What is your sensor (model, or a linky)?  Do you have real-time requirement?

is the sensor capable of generating another interrupt before you finish reading all of its data?

In the olden days, when we had a single thread of execution, and many sources of interrupts, you kept the ISR as short and quick as possible, so that it is able to keep up with many frequent interrupt requests from different sources. If you only have one source of interrupt, or the processor doesn't have other things to do while the ISR is running, then this isn't a big concern.
Just a suggestion, a popular approach was to make ISRs whose role is only to read sensor data, push it into a FIFO buffer (queue), reset/trigger the sensor or ADC to begin another conversion or sample, and exit. Processing of the buffered data was performed in a separate main loop, which popped and processed data from the queue as it appeared.
This had the advantage that the processor was in and out of the ISR in just a few clock cycles, and ready for the next interrupt from any source almost immediately. The trouble is that you have to code the queue, and you can get a buffer overrun if you don't empty the queue quicker than it fills up.
The queue can be one-sample long, more like a single variable accompanied by with a single bit flag to indicate "fullness". Or, if you worry that occasionally the processor might be caught up in another task while data is incoming, it can be larger, with a queue pointer instead of a flag.
Don't forget to disable interrupts prior to a queue interrogation/push/pop, and re-enable them afterwards, so you don't get an ISR messing with queue state in the middle of it.

This is all true, but doesn't appear to answer the question about I2C

I don't believe it's a good idea, in general.  The I2C protocol allows for clock stretching, which means that any I2C device you're trying to talk to can effectively stop your bus, or at least dork with its timing.
If you know and understand every I2C device in your system, and trust that that won't happen, then you should consider I2C comms in an ISR, using guidelines in the other answers -- but I'd still make sure all error conditions and timeouts are in place.

The sensor's data sheet does say that clock stretching can happen. Also, they have clearly mentioned that the RDY pin should be configured as interrupt to the MCU. So as per your suggestion, maybe I should simply set a flag in the ISR and do rest of the things in the main loop.

@stack-overflow--- unless there's a real reason to do otherwise, that's probably your best approach to interrupt handling here.

@stack-overflow---: Note that, just because the data sheet says that RDY should be an interrupt to the MCU doesn't mean that you have to do that: it might work best for the applications the documentation writers had in mind, but connecting it to a GPIO may work as well or better in a different application with different requirements/priorities.

If an I2C device starts mucking with your clock, is there any hope for reliable operation even if you keep I2C out of an ISR?

Usually the hardware handles the i2c at the character level and you arrange for a interrupt when the character has filled the input buffer and read it. The clock can be stopped by the slave and there may be a significant delay between characters.

I strongly agree with this. I have gotten egg on my face in the past due to this. The approach I favour with I2C is to buffer received bytes in the ISR and then get out. The I2C protocol itself has quite a bit of state in it, and better to handle all that in the main loop without holding up the handling of newly received bytes.

Well, assuming the I2C bus is running at 100 kbit/s, and you're reading/writing roughly 500 bits, the whole interrupt will take about 5 milliseconds. Do you care if your main program is paused for 5 ms?
Does the system have anything better to do with that time?
If the answer is "no", then you might be fine.
If you have other interrupts you might need to serve during that time, then you might want to move that waiting to the main program, so those interrupts can be handled. (Depending on the system, higher priority interrupts might be able to interrupt lower-priority ones.)
Of course, the "better" solution would be to program the I2C driver to do the reads and give you an interrupt e.g. after each byte, so you'd only need to interrupt the main program for the duration of copying the byte away and seeing if the transfer is done. You get to decide if that's necessary or worth the additional trouble (which depends also on how much time you have to implement and test everything, and how familiar you are with your device etc.)

It highly depends on the architecture of the processor.
As a general rule, you should not put any time-consuming operation in an isr.
Some architectures have some measures to prevent any long task in the isr. They might have a separate watchdog that triggers and resets the MCU on long tasks in the isr. For example, ESP32 with the use of FreeRTOS is doing so.
However, there are other architectures that don't care about the length of the task in isr. For example, if you set an interrupt in an AVR and it takes long, it doesn't stop anything else from performing. The only downside is if, before finishing the routine, another interrupt happens on the same pin, you should be prepared for problems!
The best practice is, as you suggested, to keep the isr routine short. Just set a flag and run the task in your main loop.
If you are using an RTOS like FreeRTOS, then there are better ways to do this. You can use a semaphore to block a task and then give it from the isr. There is a separate semaphore that gives specificity to be used from isr. It will perform a task yield right away. This will unblock the task immediately. Then, you can start communicating over the I2C bus.

If I set the flag in the ISR and perform operations in the main loop, I will be still polling for the flag to get set, right?
So what advantage would this method give? I can simply go ahead and wait for the RDY pin to get high in the main loop, can I not?

If it's single-thread firmware and the RDY signal stays at the level, yes. It will make no difference. But if the RDY signal is very short that you might miss it in the main loop, then you still need that flag.

In time-critical applications the RDY output of the chip/module/whatever can be useful to get the data or initialise a transmission immediately. Otherwise, it's still possible to read the RDY output inside the main loop periodically, depending on the application of course, and initialise the transmission for data exchange if/when necessary.
If you are to trigger the I2C transmission whilst in the GPIO interrupt then prioritisation and managing nested interrupts may make you scratch your head. Because if you use the I2C peripheral's interrupts for transmission (i.e. use the MCUs I2C peripherals and its flags or interrupts for data exchange) then things may get messy because

Some MCUs or architectures may not allow traversing through different interrupts before clearing the current interrupt. This means that you may need to be done with the GPIO interrupt first and wait for the I2C's interrupt(s).
The main code will wait for the interrupt(s) to be cleared otherwise it'll kinda stay "hung".

Instead, you may use flags: There could be hardware interrupt flags which can be read, or you can define your own flag and raise it inside the interrupt and exit. So you can check the flags inside the main loop periodically and initialise the transmission when possible. If the hardware forces you to implement a soft I2C (i.e. you write your own SCLK and SDA management) this becomes even more useful.

[General guidelines.  We don’t know the nature of the sensor, the nature of the instrument.  We’ll make working assumptions.]
The general advice is not to do serial communication in an ISR.  Don’t stay in the ISR all the time while the packed being received.  Receiving 50 bytes would take around 1ms, which is a long time for an ISR.
The classical way of handling an I2C device with a RDY (or an alarm) line is to set a flag in the ISR.  The main() loop does the serial communication when it sees the flag, then clears the flag.
A more modern way is to use direct memory access (DMA) for serial communication (if the microcontroller has DMA).  The RDY pin ISR initiates the DMA.  When the DMA is complete, it fires its own ISR.  You should be able to chain DMAs.  The last one in the chain sets the flag for the main() .
I’ve seen real time systems which did SPI communication in an ISR, because they needed a short and fixed latency.  But I’m going to assume that’s not the case in this question.  [O.P., please chime-in on this.]

The device that I am working with is a touchpad. Real-time gesture (Swipe, scroll, tap) data is expected from the device. I need to explore the DMA option.

@stack  Which MCU family are you using?

Egregious examples of systems that disable interrupts for long periods of time:

Early Macintoshes, which disabled interrupts for the entire duration of floppy disk operations, thereby preventing the original MacOS from ever being a multi-tasking operating system.

Timex/Sinclair TS 1000 computers, ran all video output in a non-maskable-interrupt service routine. A monstrous scheme where the processor would "execute" the video buffer, with custom hardware feeding the processor 80 fake "nop"s, followed by a HALT instruction, while the actual contents of the memory reads generated by executing nops were diverted to to video generation circuitry. User programs had to run during the 12% of CPU time left over in the video flyback period at the end of each video frame.


So you can do anything you want, as long as you're not preventing other things from executing that need to execute at the same time.
That being said, in my experience, I think it's a good idea to execute as little as code as possible in an interrupt service routine as you can. The main argument for that is that code in ISRs is often completely un-debuggable, and code that executes with interrupts disabled is almost always completely un-debuggable. If your code hangs because of bad code, bad cables, bad silicon, bad radio interference, bad cosmic rays, bad luck, or failure to make appropriate sacrifices to Poseidon (patron god of bits in transit), &c, you won't be able to break into the debugger to see what went wrong.
So do the absolute minimum you can in the ISR to handle the READY signal, and signal to non-ISR code that the interrupt has occurred, re-enable interrupts so that higher-priority interrupts can run, and tell the interrupt controller that you've handled the interrupt so that lower-priority interrupts can run (if that applies).

In general, an ISR should avoid doing anything that would require that it wait a non-trivial amount of time for something to happen.  If some action would require that a pin be asserted for at least 10us, driving the pin, killing time for 10us, and releasing a pin will likely be fine if nothing else in the system needs faster than 100us response time, but otherwise the preferred approach is to have each interrupt check if something can be done immediately and, if not, arrange to have another interrupt fire when the action can be performed.
If you can use hardware I2C, having an interrupt check if a device is ready to exchange a byte and, if not, schedule an interrupt when the device is ready, can be a good approach.  Unfortuantely, I've yet to find a master I2C implementation that handles acknowledgment nicely.  When using software I2C, one can receive the eight bits of a byte without clocking the acknowledge pulse, and then either send an acknowledge and clock eight more bits (if one wants more data), or send a NAK and terminate the transaction (if one doesn't want more data), but the hardware I2C modules I've used clock the ACK/NAK pulse immediately after receiving a byte of data, which in turn requires that they be told before receiving each byte of data whether more data will be desired after it.

So what's the difference of handling it nicely or non-nicely? Usually you know beforehand how many bytes you need to transfer, and so you can simply define ACK or NAK the next byte you begin to transfer. I have yet not seen such a protocol that requires you to transfer data an unknown amount before knowing which byte is last. And I believe I have seen a lot of different protocols how arbitrary messages are sent over I2C.

@Justme: If code will need to process a number of e.g. eight-byte records stored in EEPROM, being able to use a "read N bytes" routine the same way for all of the records is nicer than having to special-case the last record.  Special-casing the last record isn't impossible, of course, but it's hardly elegant.

You rarely have to think about it. Unless you are writing the I2C driver yourself. And I2C peripherals in MCUs are quite complex. For example you might be able to tell the I2C peripheral how many bytes you will transmit via DMA so it will already NAK the last byte for you. Some I2C peripherals have FIFO buffers and allow setting the NAK response so that you will trasfer one last byte or two last bytes. So you must handle three special cases, you want to reveive one byte, two bytes, or N bytes larger than 2 until 2 is left. So nothing suprirising that you need to handle special cases.

@Justme: I've never used an I2C driver I didn't write myself, and while I suppose one could process a sequence of e.g. 8-byte reads from consecutive addresses using a separate start/write-address/restart/read sequences, doing all of them with a single transaction is more elegant.

And doing a read of 8 bytes in a row is possibe. On simple AVRs with simple I2C controller, you need to transfer 8 bytes  one at a time in maybe for loop or interrupts and transfer the last byte with a request to NAK it instead of ACK. More complex MCUs with more complex I2C peripherals can transfer kilobytes in one go using DMA and thus transactions must be set up beforehand to transfer some amount like 8 bytes so the peripheral itself knows which byte is last and must be transferred with NAK instead before signaling that your 8-byte transfer is complete.

@Justme: Even if it's possible to transfer thousands of bytes in a single transaction with DMA, that's only useful if code would have something useful to do while the data is transfered.  On something like a PIC, being able to start each read while the data from the previous read is stored can improve throughput compared with having the bus sit idle during the time required to store each byte, but for many tasks code that initiates a transaction would wait for it to complete before doing anything else.

OK, but in any case, if you have a function that reads any amount of bytes you want in a loop, you know that you have one byte left and can command the peripheral to transfer the final byte to happen with a NAK.

@Justme: Such a function will have to know whether future function calls will want to read more data from the same transaction, so if one has a nested loop both the inner and outer loop will need to special-case the last iteration, versus simply having an "i2c_stop" call follow the receipt of the last byte.  Returning to the original question, if I were using a device which didn't need slave handshaking and could accommodate a bit rate reasonably commensurate with the time to bit-bang data, and if the system had no hard timing targets, I'd probably be inclined to use software bit-banging...

...perhaps with one byte per timer-tick interrupt, if the transaction would be too long to want to do in a single interrupt.

The function will know it. You always can count and know how many bytes from your example of 8 requested bytes has been tranferred or left to be transferred. So for example you can have interrupt driven reception if the next byte is the last or non-last and act accordingly to start the transfer of next byte with ACK or NAK. Common MCUs will need the ACK/NAK info before starting transfer of a single byte with an I2C peripheral. Usually MCU manufacturer examples or provided libraries handle that for you so you basically say I2C_MemRead(chipaddress, memaddress, 8 bytes thankyou, to &recvbuffer);

Yes, but the function to transfer eight bytes would have to be told whether it is handling the last group of eight within a larger transaction; when using a delayed-ack library, it wouldn't have to care.

No it would not. Only the function that transfers each byte or each block of any size must know it. I don't follow why would you have a function to read say 256 bytes in a single transaction but with a function that transfers 8 bytes at a time. Normally you would transfer all the 256 bytes in a single transaction or in multiple separate transactions of 8 bytes each. Most examples or MCU libraries don't even give you functions or API to do that, or they are complex chained operations you normally don't need.

@Justme: When using file I/O, one could perform all read operations using a primitive "open a file, read N bytes from offset O within it, and close the file", but in many cases it's both more convenient and more efficient to decompose that to "open file and seek to offset O", "read the next N bytes", and "close the file".  When working with a key/value store, with parallel data structures for keys and values, being able to read keys sequentially until one finds the key of interest, all within a single "transaction", may be much more efficient than havig to process each key read...

...as a separate transaction.  If one has enough RAM to keep all keys in RAM, that would be much faster than reading keys from EEPROM, and I guess RAM capacities have increased to the point that scanning through EEPROM would be necessary less often than used to be the case, but when working with micros that have less than 1024 bytes of RAM being able to treat an external memory as an I/O stream is useful.

As many of the other answers have said, it's generally a bad idea to do anything that stalls, in an ISR.  Instead, do the minimum possible that MUST be done RIGHT NOW, and get out.  Let some slower code handle the rest when it gets around to it.
Unfortunately, most of the already-working libraries that I've seen for hobbyists (Arduino, Raspberry Pi Pico, etc.), do stall for the entire transaction.  Thus, not good for much of anything beyond a single-tasking system, with stupidly high specs for just that one task because it's all wasted in a busy loop until the comms are finished.
I can sorta see how things came to be this way - it's a direct translation from a human-readable sequence of steps to a literal sequence that the CPU follows too - but it's (usually) not that hard to translate that human-readable sequence into a non-blocking state machine instead.  I've converted some libraries myself to do that, and once I worked the conversion mistakes out, it worked exactly like the original, except now I could do something else in the meantime too!

Essentially, everywhere that it would have stalled to wait for something, becomes another state.  Update the state variable, and leave so that something else can have the CPU while it's waiting.  Every driver has its own function that is called repeatedly, and inside that function is the state machine for that driver.  So it only runs the code that corresponds to the present state, according to that variable, which is not that far off from the original concept of just running straight down the list.
Just put a bookmark in that list (the state variable), and come back later to see if you can move on yet.  If the thing it's waiting for hasn't happened yet, the function simply returns without moving the bookmark, so next time it'll check the same thing again.
Write all of your high-level functions like that, as non-blocking state-machine drivers, and have your main loop just be a string of their function calls.  If none of them are blocking, then your service interval can be amazingly short, even for lots of complex tasks.  Often eliminates several or even all of the ISR's, because the main loop is now more than fast enough by itself, even with all kinds of everything else going on at the same time.

I don't think it would be all that hard to learn that style of programming from the start, and then we probably wouldn't have as many timing problems associated with doing slow things as we do now.  The speed and timing of some external thing no longer matters nearly as much, if at all.
But no, the vast majority of things that new programmers are supposed to "just use" and copy/paste before they really understand, are single-tasking dogs-in-mangers that tie up everything until the slow thing is done.  Use one of those in an ISR, and you've grossly limited what you can do otherwise.  (and they make ISR's more necessary, to "break the block" and do something else anyway)
